# GetElementByClass?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, twebbrowser

How can I get InnerText from Element with Class Name?

```
<div class="SomeClass" style="text-align: left; display: block;"></div>

<div class="SomeClass" style="text-align: left; display: block;">Sometext</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok the class maybe more than one you must use a TstringList i made function for you:

```
function GetInnersByClass(const Doc: IDispatch; const classname: string;var Lst:TStringList): Integer;
var
  Document: IHTMLDocument2;     // IHTMLDocument2 interface of Doc
  Body: IHTMLElement2;          // document body element
  Tags: IHTMLElementCollection; // all tags in document body
  Tag: IHTMLElement;            // a tag in document body
  I: Integer;                   // loops thru tags in document body
begin
  Lst.Clear;
  Result := 0 ;
  // Check for valid document: require IHTMLDocument2 interface to it
  if not Supports(Doc, IHTMLDocument2, Document) then
    raise Exception.Create('Invalid HTML document');
  // Check for valid body element: require IHTMLElement2 interface to it
  if not Supports(Document.body, IHTMLElement2, Body) then
    raise Exception.Create('Can''t find <body> element');
  // Get all tags in body element ('*' => any tag name)
  Tags := Body.getElementsByTagName('*');
  // Scan through all tags in body
  for I := 0 to Pred(Tags.length) do
  begin
    // Get reference to a tag
    Tag := Tags.item(I, EmptyParam) as IHTMLElement;
    // Check tag's id and return it if id matches
    if AnsiSameText(Tag.className, classname) then
    begin
      Lst.Add(Tag.innerHTML);
      Inc(Result);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

result is how many class each with function

and you cam use it with this sample :

```
var
  lst : TStringList;
begin
  //
  lst := TStringList.Create;
  GetInnersByClass(wb1.Document,'SameClass',lst);
  ShowMessage(lst.Text);
  lst.Free;
end;
```

dont forget add MSHTML unit to main unit.

Answer (score 1):

hi for find value in HTML doc yo must have special property same id .

it is important special property  .

for example you can find inner text with this function but with id :

```
function GetInnerElementById(const Doc: IDispatch; const Id: string): WideString;
var
  Document: IHTMLDocument2;     // IHTMLDocument2 interface of Doc
  Body: IHTMLElement2;          // document body element
  Tags: IHTMLElementCollection; // all tags in document body
  Tag: IHTMLElement;            // a tag in document body
  I: Integer;                   // loops thru tags in document body
begin
  Result :='';
  // Check for valid document: require IHTMLDocument2 interface to it
  if not Supports(Doc, IHTMLDocument2, Document) then
    raise Exception.Create('Invalid HTML document');
  // Check for valid body element: require IHTMLElement2 interface to it
  if not Supports(Document.body, IHTMLElement2, Body) then
    raise Exception.Create('Can''t find <body> element');
  // Get all tags in body element ('*' => any tag name)
  Tags := Body.getElementsByTagName('*');
  // Scan through all tags in body
  for I := 0 to Pred(Tags.length) do
  begin
    // Get reference to a tag
    Tag := Tags.item(I, EmptyParam) as IHTMLElement;
    // Check tag's id and return it if id matches
    if AnsiSameText(Tag.id, Id) then
    begin
      Result := Tag.innerHTML;
      Break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

you must use the "MSHTML" unit...

and you can use it with sample:

```
</head>
<body>
<div id="TESTID">sametext</div>
</body>


ShowMessage(GetElementById(wb1.Document,'TESTID'));
```

if you have to use SomeClass tell me i give new function to you....

Comment: Yes please must use class name :)