# 1 How can I get InnerText from Element with Class Name using the new TEdgeBrowser in delphi 10.4?

Tags: delphi, tedgebrowser

I am trying to migrate from an old code using twebrowser to the new tedgebrowser, but the edgebrowser doesn't have the same properties, so I can't use my old function anymore

I was using the function that I got here:
[GetElementByClass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443694/getelementbyclass/13444081#13444081)

```
  function GetInnersByClass(const Doc: IDispatch; const classname: string;var Lst:TStringList):Integer;

  var
    Document: IHTMLDocument2;     // IHTMLDocument2 interface of Doc
    Body: IHTMLElement2;          // document body element
    Tags: IHTMLElementCollection; // all tags in document body
    Tag: IHTMLElement;            // a tag in document body
    I: Integer;                   // loops thru tags in document body
  begin
    Lst.Clear;
    Result := 0 ;
    // Check for valid document: require IHTMLDocument2 interface to it
    if not Supports(Doc, IHTMLDocument2, Document) then
        raise Exception.Create('Invalid HTML document');

    // Check for valid body element: require IHTMLElement2 interface to it
    if not Supports(Document.body, IHTMLElement2, Body) then
        raise Exception.Create('Can''t find <body> element');

    // Get all tags in body element ('*' => any tag name)
    Tags := Body.getElementsByTagName('*');

    // Scan through all tags in body
    for I := 0 to Pred(Tags.length) do
    begin
        // Get reference to a tag
        Tag := Tags.item(I, EmptyParam) as IHTMLElement;

        // Check tag's id and return it if id matches
        if AnsiSameText(Tag.className, classname) then
        begin
            Lst.Add(Tag.innerHTML);
          Inc(Result);
        end;
      end;
  end;
```

Then, for example,  I call it using:
GetInnersByClass(WebBrowser1.Document,'class name',lst);

And I get the innertext from the 'class name' into the variable lst

But TEdgeBrowser doesn't have the Document property.

It doesn't have to be the same function. What I need is to get the innertext from an Elemment loaded in the TEdgeBrowser.

Does anyone have any ideia how to do this?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Check this article on Embarcadero [blog](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/execute-scripts-and-view-source-with-tedgebrowser/).

You have to run the script and pass the result to Delphi.

Edit:

Check this demo (you can find it on the GitHub too)
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\Samples\Object Pascal\VCL\WebBrowser\Edge

And add code like this:

```pascal
procedure TfrmMain.ToolButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  var LS := TFile.ReadAllText('EdgeScript.js');
  EdgeBrowser.ExecuteScript(LS);
end;
```

EdgeScript.js:

```js
var set = document.querySelectorAll("a.gb_d");
var values = [];
for (const elem of set) {
  values.push(elem.href);
}
encodeURI(JSON.stringify({length: set.length, values: values}));_
```

Navigate to google.com and run the script. This is my code to find all anchors with specified classname. Modify javacript to find your element and return InnerText.

Comment: I had checked the article before. It didin't help me. Could you give an easy example how to run a script that return some result to a variable?  Maybe I can do the rest with my code. Thank you

Comment: Check my edited answer. I hope it helps you.